# I want to emphasize how often I played basketball in the past. So,

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to emphasize how often I played basketball in the past. So,

> 1. I would play basketball more often than ***anything else.***
> 2. I would play basketball more often than **whichever I did.**
> 3. I would play basketball more often than ***whatever I did.***
> 4. I would play basketball more often than ***I did anything.***

Which one is the best choice? What would you choose? If the others are not correct, what is the reason?

Comment: Only #1 means what you intend; #2 doesn't mean anything without further context, and ##3-4 are self-contradictory, since basketball is included in both *whatever* and *anything*

Comment: If you're talking about the past, I'd rather use "I used to play basketball..." instead of "I would play basketball...". To use "I would" you should say (or it should be clear from context) under what particular circumstances you would play.

Comment: @StoneyB is correct in pointing out the contradiction, which is really included in all sentences but #1.  It's similar to saying *I would play basketball more often than I would play football or baseball or basket ball.

Comment: Thank you guys. Then how about this? "I would play basketball more often than I did anything else."

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence sounds just about right. The rest sounds odd or needs more information attached to it, that is, they are not ideally independent. In the sentence you suggested in your comment,

> "I would play basketball more often than I did anything else.",

if you wanted to emphasize that you played Basketball more than *'anything else'*, you should specified what that *'anything else'* is. Or you could simply say:

> "I would play basketball more often than I played anything else."

Answer (score 0):

A shorter version would be:

> I was always playing basketball.

Comment: Yes, except it wouldn't necessarily be true, unless you intend to say that you never slept, ate, went to school... etc.

Comment: This is a very common construct and is not meant to be taken literally.

Answer (score 0):

I like (watching) basketball too, (especially 90's), so how about these

"My love was always with rim!"

"I thought I could fly like MJ".

"My dream was being drafted by GSW as a number 1 pick".

---

P.S

To mods, please delete if this sounds like a rant.